# Raspbian Put monitor to sleep at night and wake in morning

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

I have my Raspbian running Chromium in kiosk mode and works nicely. However, I would like it to turn the HDMI display off at 10pm and wake it up at 7am. I could not find such a setting in Raspbian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using `xset dpms force off` to turn off the display. This command uses *Display Power Management Signaling*.

In a cron job, you'll need to set the `DISPLAY` variable, so that the crontab entries become something like:

```
0   22  *   *   *   DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force off
0   7   *   *   *   DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on
```

Make sure the X server is started with `-dpms`.

Comment: This will run every minute of 22h and 7h. @andré-düwel's answer configures the cronjob to run at 22:00 and 7:00 and better answers the original question.

Comment: @Chadi Running repeatedly might be better if, for example, the device was turned off at 7 am.

Comment: Good catch. I fixed it above. Thanks, @André-Düwel and Chadi!

Comment: this worked when other suggestions for cec-util and tvresource failed to work (Raspberry Pi 4B) failed to work

Comment: How does one "make sure the X server is started with -dpms"?  I am running a Pi4 with stock Raspian.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look into HDMI CEC which allows you to send commands such as power on/off via HDMI to a TV set. There's a libcec for this, as well as an cec-client. For instance, this blog post about switching on/off a TV may help: https://timleland.com/raspberry-pi-turn-tv-onoff-cec/

Then set up a cron job to run cec-client in the evening and the morning.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using a monitor which is not CEC compatible.

Comment: Maybe you should add relevant commands to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Like [Steffen Uhlig](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/68151/97653) wrote, using `xset dpms force [on|off]` is the solution for normal displays. Please note that his cronjob is running every minute in the specified hour.

`crontab -e` (as normal pi user) will allow you to add a cronjob, where you just need to add the following lines at the end:

```
0   22  *   *   *   DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force off
0   7   *   *   *   DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on
```

Comment: Good find. This should really be a comment to the answer you refer to, but I know you can't post comments yet.

Comment: thats my problem, feel free to add the comment to the accepted answer or suggest an edit :)

Comment: I added that to my cron: off at 22 and on at 07.  To make a try, from command line I executed the `off` command, it worked. Then I executed the `on`, also worked but after a while the display turned off again. Second time executed `on` command and again display turned off after a while.  Don't realize why